# Generate Google API access_token in Google Colab from Python

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token, google-colaboratory, google-api-python-client

I need to generate an `access_token` with some specific scopes `['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']` from Python inside Google Colab.

By default, Google Colab provides a function inside [colabtools](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools) to authenticate the user.

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
print('Authenticated')
```

But the credential file generated contains a list of fixed scopes, not including the ones I need.

```py
import os
with open(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']) as f:
  print(f.read())
```

```
...
"scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
...
```

I have tried to generate a valid Credentials token with the `google-auth` library `enter code here`using the [google.auth.Credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.credentials.html) class and also the [google.oauth2.Credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html) class. I can generate valid instances of the classes, but when I check the token is None.

Is there a way to generate valid `access_token` for Google API with custom scopes from Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a VM with Google Colab, you can set the scopes for the service account on that vm with the following command (example):

```
gcloud compute instances set-service-account example-instance \
   --service-account my-sa-123@my-project-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
   --scopes compute-rw,storage-ro
```

Then, when authenticating from within Python, the generated credentials will contain the correct scopes.